# Open a URL with a PHP within it using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch data from a URL using cURL...this is something I would be able to do but the URL that I want to fetch data from has a section of php code within it - i.e. the URL is populated using a values generated by an earlier section of code.

I want to access the URL, take the figures out of it and then plug those figures into something else. At the minute I am hitting a bit of a roadblock as the php doesn't populate the URL...any ideas?

The code I am using is:

```
    $url = "https://*START OF API ADDRESS*<?php echo $request_ids; ?>*END OF API ADDRESS*";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
    $rates = json_decode($result, true);

    // Save result
    $rates['last_updated'] = time();
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($rates));
}
```

Comment: Then it is probably not populated by PHP. The PHP code should run when you cURL to it, but javascript/AJAX wont run

Comment: use dots to concatenate strings, and extract the variable name from the php code, remove the php code, and add the variable name? try  `$url = "https://*START OF API ADDRESS*".$request_id."*END OF API ADDRESS*";`